# Flattening nested JSON file into a PySpark DF

Tags: json, pyspark

I am new to PySpark and I am struggling with flattening a nested json file into a PySpark data frame.

I need to define the schema for the JSON data.  I know how to define schema for regular json files but I get stuck at defining the schema for this case. I need **generalised** version of this example, not the hard coded version.

In this example I have a verified manifest and the string `AB1` should go under `verifiedManifest_name` and quantity should go under `verifiedManifest_quantity`. I don't know how many inputs to the verifiedManifest I'll have nor how they will be named.

`"verifiedManifest":{"AB1":{"quantity":1}, "DE5":{"quantity":5}, "AG1":{"quantity":10}}`

Output for this case will look like this:

```
verifiedManifest_name    verifiedManifest_quantity
AB1                            1
DE5                            5
AG1                            10
DOL1                           100
BG1                            3
etc...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose you have your data in a JSON file:

```
input_df = spark.read.text('./test.json', wholetext = True)
input_string = input_df.collect()[0]['value']
input_dict = eval(input_string)

df = spark.createDataFrame([
    (input_dict['verifiedManifest'],)
], ['verifiedManifest'])

df = (
    df
    .select(f.explode(f.col('verifiedManifest')))
    .withColumnRenamed('key', 'verifiedManifest_name')
    .withColumn('verifiedManifest_value', f.element_at(f.col('value'), 'quantity'))
    .select('verifiedManifest_name', 'verifiedManifest_value')
)

df.show(truncate= False)
```

and the output will look like:

```
+---------------------+----------------------+                                  
|verifiedManifest_name|verifiedManifest_value|
+---------------------+----------------------+
|AB1                  |1                     |
|AG1                  |10                    |
|DE5                  |5                     |
+---------------------+----------------------+
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `stack` function for all the columns dynamically, by reading using `read.json` method.

**`Example:`**

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import *
str= """{"verifiedManifest":{"AB1":{"quantity":1}, "DE5":{"quantity":5}, "AG1":{"quantity":10}}}"""
#read the json string using spark read json
df = spark.read.json(sc.parallelize([str]))

#unnest struct and select dynamically
df1 = df.select("verifiedManifest.*")

#length of columns
sz_cols = len(df1.columns).__format__('')

#create dynamic stack function and alias of output column names
stack_expr = f"stack({sz_cols}" +"," +','.join([f'"{f}",{f}.*' for f in df1.columns]) + ") as (verifiedManifest_name, verifiedManifest_quantity)"
df1.select(expr(stack_expr)).show(10,False)
#+---------------------+-------------------------+
#|verifiedManifest_name|verifiedManifest_quantity|
#+---------------------+-------------------------+
#|AB1                  |1                        |
#|AG1                  |10                       |
#|DE5                  |5                        |
#+---------------------+-------------------------+
```